# Chemistry Self Education

Tags: materials

I want to learn chemistry. I did not have the benefit of studying it when I was in highschool, and I was always intimidated by it (I feel it's more rote memorization rather than understanding - I'm more of a Physics and Math kinda guy).

Anyway, what are the concepts that I need to learn?

**How, and what resources are you going to use to homeschool Chemistry to a teenager?**

In that studying it would put the student on par with a normal highschool student.

Some Nice Stuff:

```
Topics for a Normal Highschool Chemistry Curriculum
and Maybe AP and Honors Program Curriculums?
Comprehensive Textbooks
Exams and Self Testing Resources
```

Comment: This is too broad for the site as it stands.

Comment: @jonsca are the answers no good either?

Comment: @Amaterasu I am leaving everything intact, but in the future it's best to flag or vote to close questions that are too broad.

Comment: The edit doesn't really change the breadth of this topic - there are already several answers to get you going and a better use of Chem.SE would be to ask specific questions about problems that arise in your understanding of the material in the answers' links.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at free online courses, e.g. at [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry). To my opinion, this can however not replace the real experience of endless, often frustrating hours in the lab ;) - chemistry is an experimental science.

Answer (score 2):

There are several concepts you need to learn, and the direction these will take will depend on your area(s) of interest.

To that end, the following are some resources that could be of help:

[Khan Academy tutorials](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry), these start with the fundamental concepts of the atom, periodic table, orbitals and electrons, chemical reactions, stoichiometry, states of matter, gas laws etc.

[ChemTutor](http://www.chemtutor.com/) has some basic concepts to start of with, including measurement and pretty much all that Khan Academy has.

Something, as someone in education, I need to emphasise, and that is to test yourself - there are some online self-testing sites, such as [this one from the University of Toronto](http://www.chem.utoronto.ca/undergrad/webexams.php).

Most of all, don't fear chemistry, it is a lot of fun and requires substantial problem solving and experimentation - you can buy some of these at toy stores and many experiments can be done at home - such as these from [Home Science Tools](http://www.hometrainingtools.com/chemistry-kits/c/11/).