# What is an intuitive explanation for Electron Configurations

Tags: electronic-configuration

I'm sort of [self studying Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/chemistry-self-education). I'm now getting stuck wrapping my head around a concept (and I realize it was the same concept I had difficulty grasping years ago) and that is **Electron Configurations**.

I know that perhaps due to the nature of chemistry it is non-intuitive. However, I want an explanation that is more than "This is a bunch of numbers and letters that follow a pattern. Live with it" - which seems to just be the explanations I'm getting when I went to school.

So, my question is, what are Electron Configurations, and how would you explain them intuitively?

Answer (score 3):

Electron configurations are a bunch of numbers and letters, and they also follow a pattern. But there is also a logic behind the whole thing.

Basically, chemists use electron configurations to see in which [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) the electrons are found. From this several things can be derived, most of all the reactivity of said electrons (which is where the chemistry happens).

The intuitive answer is this: Electron configurations are a way of telling in which atomic orbitals the electrons are put in, according to the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) and the [Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). Decoding it is pretty easy, as it always follows this pattern:
$n$$(s|p|d|f)^x$ where $n$ is the main quantum number (or shell number), $(s|p|d|f)$ denotes the atomic orbitals with the quantum number and $x$ is the number of electrons found in the orbitals.

The orbital "groups" ($p$, $d$, $f$) contain several "orbitals" (side note: an orbital is strictly seen a one-electron function) where two electrons with opposite spin fit in. $p$ has 3 ($p_x,\; p_y,\; p_z$), $d$ has 5 ($d_{xy},\; d_{xz},\; d_{yz},\; d_{x^2-y^2},\; d_{z^2}$) and $f$ even more. This means that the maximal number of electrons in the $p$ group is $6$, and in the $d$ group $10$. So when you fill in the electrons according to the aufbau principle, you have to go to the next orbital group when you reach this number.

**Bottom line:** Every electron in an atom is defined by the four quantum numbers $n$ (main or principal quantum number), $l$ (azimuthal), $m_l$ (magnetic) and $m_s$ (spin). Using the electron configuration we can derive the first three of these four numbers.